Is it possible to restrict a Google Cloud IAM Role to Impersonate only one specific Service Account?
I am using Privileged Access Manager(PAM) to temporarily assign roles to users/principals.
I know I can create an entitlement to assign the Service Account Token Creator role to a user account to enable that user to impersonate any service account.
Is there a way to restrict that role to only allow access to one specific service account and not just grant the ability to impersonate ANY service account? Or some other way to create an entitlement to do that?
I feel like this could be possible with IAM conditions but I was not able to figure out how to specify the specific service account resource in the IAM condition.

PAM is only at project level for now. Maybe it will be at resource level a day, and you will be able to achieve this.
